# What words should I capitalize in the title of a PhD dissertation?

Tags: writing-style

I am unsure about how to capitalize the title of my dissertation. In my case, I am wondering about  "testing" and "empirical":

> Four Essays on the empirical testing of the Efficiency Hypothesis

Should I capitalize gerunds?

Comment: Check the journal style guide, or see what the journal has done on other published papers.

Comment: It's a PHD-thesis. Unfortunately, there is no style guide.

Comment: OK, look at the title pages of other theses in your department or in the library. Check with the thesis secretary.

Comment: I found a similar scientific article with capitalised "Empirical testing".

Comment: Wait, but why have you capitalized "Essays"?

Comment: Where are you? I was taught that UK-style is to only capitalise the first word, and it's a US style to capitalise any other words. Are there local conventions like that where you are?

Comment: Off topic, but I might suggest omitting the "the" unless you are referring to some single particular empiracl testing so idenrified in the literature.

Comment: My school had a detailed style guide for theses and dissertations that told you exactly what to capitalize in titles.

Comment: Are you *citing* your already-written dissertation?  Or are you deciding how the title should appear on the title page of the dissertation you are currently writing?  Those are not necessarily going to follow the same formats.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The quickest solution (for me, at least), is to type in your title at https://capitalizemytitle.com. It gives correct title capitalization in many formal styles. And it has detailed information to explain the rules it follows.

Style guides vary, but generally, any word of any grammatical type that is four or five letters or longer is capitalized. (Different style guides differ on the four- or five-letter cut-off.)

For just about all style guides, "Testing" and "Empirical" are definitely capitalized.

Comment: It gives me "Four Essays on the Empirical Testing of the Efficiency Hypothesis"

Comment: @TobKel, I'd agree (from a traditional viewpoint) with that idea...

Comment: @TobKel ... that is exactly right for "title case", which is common in the US.  Perhaps not common everywhere, though.

Comment: Could put the "Efficiency Hypothesis" in itallics for emphasis if it is the name of a particular well known hypothesis in the field?

Comment: What an amazingly useful site. I am in awe of people that create these beautiful, single-purpose websites that do one thing and do them brilliantly. Thanks for sharing, I didn't know that it existed.

Answer (score 7):

I think there are three plausible options.

> Four Essays on the Empirical Testing of the Efficiency Hypothesis

This is [title case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_case): you capitalise almost all words. The only words not capitalised will be things like articles, conjunctions and short prepositions (and perhaps some other words where a lower case initial letter is significant, e.g. "E. coli"). Exact rules vary, but "on", "of" and "the" would be lower case in all major versions.

> Four essays on the empirical testing of the efficiency hypothesis

This is (normal) sentence case. In some disciplines, the titles of articles are usually in sentence case, and IMO it makes sense to do the same for theses in those disciplines.

> Four essays on the empirical testing of the Efficiency Hypothesis

This is still sentence case, but regarding Efficiency Hypothesis as a proper noun. If you capitalise it when it appears in the text of your thesis, obviously you should also capitalise it in the title.

In particular, capitalising "Essays" but not "empirical testing" would be inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a language maven, but I'd think that both Empirical and Testing should be capitalized. They seem to be especially important words in the title - the essence of it, actually. The work is about empirical testing, after all.

Some might ask you to capitalize all words in a title, even articles.

In a thesis, your advisor should have good advice.

Comment: Maybe _not_ "articles" or "prepositions"...? (unless they're part of the official name of something?)

Answer (score 0):

> the Efficiency Hypothesis

I doubt that's a good choice of phrase for a PhD title, regardless of capitalization. "efficiency" comes up everywhere. This is super-vague. At least somethin like "Smith's Efficiency Hypothesis" or "The [process name] efficiency Hypothesis" if that's the process you want to make efficient. Remember, the PhD title will be read not just by people in your specific subfield, but by people with very diverse backgrounds.

Comment: This really isn't an answer to the question at all.